# boost thread - use local variable as parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm writing a C++ class using boost threads. The purpose of the class is to start a new thread, generate in this thread every 2 seconds an object called LocationEstimatePF and call a callback function in another class, giving this LocationEstimatePF as parameter.

Something like this:

```
void Simulator::startSimulation() {

    running_ = true;
    sim_thread_ = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&Simulator::run, this));

}

void Simulator::run() {

    for (;;) {
        if(running_){
        try {

            //Generate estimate
            LocationEstimatePF estimate(1,2,3,4,5);

            engine_.updateLocationEstimate(estimate);

            //Wait for 2 seconds for next estimate
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2000));

        } catch (boost::thread_interrupted&) {
            return;
        }
        }
    }

}
```

The engine and thread are defined as a member variable in the .h file as follows:

```
InMapsEngine& engine_;
boost::thread* sim_thread_;
```

And the callback method in the Engine class:

```
void updateLocationEstimate(const LocationEstimatePF& estimate) { Log::info("Test");};
```

Now when I run startSimulation() above, I get a segmentation fault. Now, I know that engine_ is correctly set, I can even call other methods without a problem. I believe the problem lies in the local variable, do you guys have any idea? The "Test" in the engine is never printed.

Here the stack trace:

```
I/DEBUG   (11781): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     r0 00000000  r1 66da3e68  r2 00000001  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     r4 001e8480  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 40490000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     r8 62055ab0  r9 66da3e68  sl 3f800000  fp 40000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     ip 00000001  sp 66da3e60  lr 61864604  pc 616b0a4e  cpsr 60000030
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d0  4158b82020000000  d1  3f110612c247fff9
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d2  400b8ae93f57e022  d3  400b8ae943697f55
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d4  c2ef3a464385c588  d5  407eb7ac40c0a412
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d6  40dd1ce4bec8a7a3  d7  0062e080400b8ae9
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d8  3fd9b1b440400000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d16 3fe0000000000000  d17 4158b82000000000
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d18 3fd7e1cb1c913900  d19 3fc41a88bb99a35a
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 3fac47489540ee39
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d22 3f8293cfee13fd75  d23 3f96eb1df9afa780
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d24 3f5871d465fee876  d25 3f6e1beddd51e95d
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d26 3f30d636137869f2  d27 3f439d2605c8ef21
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d28 3fe66819a15509c2  d29 3f13d11c3e64b4a4
I/DEBUG   (11781):     d30 bef375cbdb605373  d31 3f8b5c41074afda1
I/DEBUG   (11781):     scr 80000093
I/DEBUG   (11781): 
I/DEBUG   (11781): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (11781):     #00  pc 00367a4e  /data/app-lib/de.tum.ei.lmt.inmaps3d-1/libInMapsJNI.so (Simulator::run()+69)
I/DEBUG   (11781):     #01  pc 0051b600  /data/app-lib/de.tum.ei.lmt.inmaps3d-1/libInMapsJNI.so
I/DEBUG   (11781): 
I/DEBUG   (11781): stack:
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e20  83a88000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e24  02ed263d  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e28  83a88000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e2c  02ed263d  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e30  61f05dd3  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e34  0004f4cf  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e38  532719d5  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-mark-stack (deleted)
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e3c  176a6e38  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e40  61c0ee99  /data/app-lib/de.tum.ei.lmt.inmaps3d-1/libInMapsJNI.so
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e44  001e8480  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e48  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e4c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e50  40490000  /system/lib/libskia.so (GrGLCaps::initStencilFormats(GrGLContextInfo const&)+808)
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e54  62055ab0  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e58  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e5c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):     #00  66da3e60  001e8480  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e64  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e68  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e6c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e70  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e78  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e7c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e80  3f800000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e84  40000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e88  40400000  /system/lib/libskia.so
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e8c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e90  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e94  40490000  /system/lib/libskia.so (GrGLCaps::initStencilFormats(GrGLContextInfo const&)+808)
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e98  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (11781):          66da3e9c  16c16c17
```

Comment: Is `Log::info()` thread-safe?

Comment: Post LocationEstimatePF constructor.

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace so that we know in which line the segfault happens?

Comment: @Sam Yes, it is just printf

Answer (score 0):

Your InMapsEngine reference is not initialized or do you set it up outside of the class constructor ?

> InMapsEngine **&** engine_;

You could use member object instead

> InMapsEngine engine_;

... or set your reference before the thread calls it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your stacktrace exactly what is going wrong, but it could be that you have multiple threads trying to access your shared engine resource at the same time.

One way to do this would be to use a mutex and condition variable to signal to your threads when your engine resource is available to them.:

```
try{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(engine_mutex);
    m_condition.wait(lock);
    engine_.updateLocationEstimate(estimate);
    m_condition.notify_one();
}
catch (boost::thread_interrupted&) {
    return;
}
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2000));
```

Though you may want to use a regular lock instead if you want to include your sleep in the try block.  Just remember to unlock.